`shell date` is not updating for a recursively expanded variable in make
I am trying to learn make and I have come across recursively expanded variables. I understand that these variables are expanded during invocation and not at the time of definition. However, I get the same date inside the test rule both the times.
Makefile:
LOCAL_TIME=${shell date +"%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S"}

test:
    @echo ${LOCAL_TIME}
    sleep 2
    @echo ${LOCAL_TIME}

I get the following output:
2024:05:14:11:40:05
sleep 2
2024:05:14:11:40:05

Am I missing any details regarding recursively expanded variables here?

The text for the script to be executed is all expanded at once.  So, the shell command runs twice, but it runs twice BEFORE the commands are run.  So, just embed the date command in the command list.

In your Makefile, LOCAL_TIME is a constant (the name make-variable used in the man-page is a bit misleading), set when the makefile is run. Why would you expect that the valid suddenly changes during the execution of a make recipe?

For user1934428, that variable is not "constant".  It's assigned with =, which means it's re-expanded every time it's used in the makefile.

The function is evaluated when make parses the recipe. If you want to defer that until the recipe actually runs, you'll have to use something like eval.
However, in this case, the obvious and trivial fix is to just inline the command.
date_cmd=date +"%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S"

test:
    @$(date_cmd)
    sleep 2
    @$(date_cmd)

Tangentially, that's a really weird date format. You're probably better off with the ISO standard format %F (aka %y-%m-%d)
